# Subsite Migration from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 

Tags: 2007, migration, administration, content-deployment

We want to Migrate a subsite from SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 without doing a content DB Migration, we tried with "import/export" commands and failed.

Please let me know if we have any other easy way of doing this ?

May be using Powershell or custom code...

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of migration tools out there. Not sure if you have budget constraints but generally you tend to get more out of a migration toolset than the time it takes to develop something in house to do the migration. There's a lot of migration solutions out there, from a lot of different vendors. Bamboo Solutions, Axceler, Metalogix, and MetaVis Technologies come to mind.

I don't think you'd have a lot of success with export/import, backup/restore, or raw DB migration simply because the versions are different. You need a tool that will translate WSS3/2007 to 2010. I believe the vast majority of migration toolsets (from companies like those listed above) have upgrade capability also. Many of them also offer trial periods to sample the software.

Comment: Our Management is decided to buy a tool to do this however it seems that it may take some time, there are few sites/site collections has to be migrated immediately and they are huge in size, so will be happy if able to find a simple/small tool just to migrate few sites/site collections in the meantime.

Comment: As Alicia suggested, I think I'd probably use the trial of a tool to help with the immediate need. This also gives you a chance to make sure that's the tool you want to buy.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just setup a test server with SharePoint 2010, take a backup of the MOSS 2007 database, restore it to the test/migration server, upgrade the database to 2010 with DB Attach, and then temporarily attach the upgraded 2007 Database to the production farm long enough to move the site collections with Powershell via:

```
Move-SPSite <http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName> -DestinationDatabase <DestinationContentDb>
```

- [Attach databases and upgrade to SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263299.aspx)
- [Move site collections between databases (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825328.aspx)